# Printing lists in alphabetical order using .sort

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

Everything in my code is returning what i expect, until i get to the last portion. The sort method is not returning my list in alphabetical order. I keep trying different vectors of corrections, but am brand new to python/coding, and clearly don't have a grasp on what i need to do. Please help. How do i concatenate these strings then print them out in alphabetical order:

Dickens**
Hardy**
Tolstoy**
Twain**
Uris**

```
books = ['War and Peace', 'Huckleberry Finn', 'The Return of the Native', 'A     Christmas Carol', 'Exodus']
authors = ['Tolstoy', 'Twain', 'Hardy', 'Dickens' 'Uris']

authorBooks = []
   for i in range(len(books)):
   authorBooks = [authors[i] + ' wrote ' + books[i]]
   authorBooks = list()
   while i < 4:
       print(''.join(authorBooks))
       break
authorBooks = []
for i in range(len(books)):
    authorBooks = [authors[i] + ' wrote ' + books[i]]
    authorBooks = list()
    while i < 4:
        print(''.join(authorBooks))
        break
```

Comment: What's the point of those `while` loops if you unconditionally `break` them after the first iteration?

Comment: One of the basics of getting help is providing code that will run to illustrate the problem. Copy the code posted in the question and try to run it. It will not run for the most basic reason "indentation error"

Answer (score 0):

there's a better way to concatenate one to one mapping lists with same indexes

```
books = ['War and Peace', 'Huckleberry Finn', 'The Return of the Native', 'A Christmas Carol', 'Exodus']
authors = ['Tolstoy', 'Twain', 'Hardy', 'Dickens', 'Uris']

concatenated = []
for x, y in zip(authors, books):
    concatenated.append("{} wrote {}".format(x,y))

concatenated.sort()
print("\n".join(concatenated))
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If their is no restriction around using the existing list you can simply add the string to the existing list and avoid creating new list altogether

```
books = ['War and Peace', 'Huckleberry Finn', 'The Return of the Native', 'A Christmas Carol', 'Exodus']
authors = ['Tolstoy', 'Twain', 'Hardy', 'Dickens', 'Uris']
books = sorted([authors[i] + ' wrote ' + books[i] for i in range(len(authors))])
print(books)
###
['Dickens wrote A Christmas Carol', 'Hardy wrote The Return of the Native', 'Tolstoy wrote War and Peace', 'Twain wrote Huckleberry Finn', 'Uris wrote Exodus']
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Any advice on getting it to print out in a list format, top to bottom? I tried the following code. It removes the brackets and singles quotes, but only the last item drops down to a new line. I want each item to be on a new line. 

    print(''.join(books), end= '\n')

Comment: Try: - print(*books, sep='\n')

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted` from the [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) functions to order them (to reverse the order just pass a further parameter `reverse=True`) and `zip` to make pairing. I assumed the both lists have the same size, otherwise `zip` will automatically drop the last values of the longest one. In the ordering I didn't not distinguish between upper and lower case characters, `casefold()`.

```
books = ['War and Fish', 'War and Peace', 'Huckleberry Finn', 'The Return of the Native', 'A     Christmas Carol', 'Exodus']
authors = ['xxx', 'Tolstoy', 'Twain', 'Hardy', 'Dickens' 'Uris']

pairs = list(zip(books, authors))

order_by_books = sorted(pairs, key=lambda pair: pair[0].casefold())
order_by_author = sorted(pairs, key=lambda pair: pair[1].casefold())

print('By books name:')
for book, author in order_by_books:
    print(f'{author} wrote "{book}"')

print('By authors:')
for book, author in order_by_author:
    print(f'{author} wrote "{book}"')
```